# Page reloads after uploading a file using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using ajax to upload a file to the server and generate a url for a specific purpose. But whenever the file upload is successful, the page reloads automatically. Even the console shows "File uploaded" for a second and then reloads. Can someone help me sort this problem.
Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut ico n" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>InShare - File Sharing Made Easy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="./logo.png" alt="Inshare logo" class="logo">
    <section class="upload-container">
        <form action="">
            <div class="drop-zone">
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <img src="file.svg" draggable="false" class="center" alt="File Icon">
                    <img src="file.svg" draggable="false" class="left" alt="File Icon">
                    <img src="file.svg" draggable="false" class="right" alt="File Icon">
                </div>
                <input type="file" id="fileInput">
                <div class="title">Drop your Files here or, <span id="browseBtn">browse</span></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="bg-progress"></div>

            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="status">Uploading...</div>
                <div class="percent-container">
                    <span class="percentage" id="progressPercent">0</span>%
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sharing-container">
            <p class="expire">Link expires in 24 hrs</p>


            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="fileURL" readonly>
                <img src="./copy-icon.svg" id="copyURLBtn" alt="copy to clipboard icon">
            </div> 


            <p class="email-info">Or Send via Email</p>
            <div class="email-container">
                <form id="emailForm">
                    <div class="filed">
                        <label for="fromEmail">Your email</label>
                        <input type="email" autocomplete="email" required name="from-email" id="fromEmail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="filed">
                        <label for="toEmail">Receiver's email</label>
                        <input type="email" required autocomplete="receiver" name="to-email" id="toEmail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="send-btn-container">
                        <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="image-vector"></div>
    <div class="toast">Sample message</div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the ajax section of javascript code:

```
const uploadFile = () => {
  console.log("file added uploading");

  files = fileInput.files;
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("myfile", files[0]);

  //show the uploader
  progressContainer.style.display = "block";

  // upload file
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", uploadURL);
  xhr.send(formData);

  // listen for response which will give the link
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      onFileUploadSuccess(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

};

const onFileUploadSuccess = (res) => {
  fileInput.value = ""; // reset the input
  console.log("Uploaded");

  // remove the disabled attribute from form btn & make text send
  emailForm[2].removeAttribute("disabled");
  emailForm[2].innerText = "Send";
  progressContainer.style.display = "none"; // hide the box

  const { file: url } = JSON.parse(res);
  console.log(url);
  sharingContainer.style.display = "block";
  fileURL.value = url;
};
```

Even e.preventDefault() has been used to prevent page reload. But still it does. Can someone help me solve this. Thank you in advance..

Comment: Your button is of type `submit`. Just change it to `<input type="button">`, or `<button type="button">`, both work as long as you specify it to NOT be a submit

Comment: It doesn't work. The button is not used for file uploading.

Comment: Then how does the upload start ?  Is there still some code that you have not shared ?